# Why are there so many refcounts for my variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sys

In my attempt to understanding the Python GIL (in Python 3.7.6.
), I played with `sys.getrefcount()` and the results are a bit bizarre.

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.getrefcount) for `sys.getrefcount(object)`

> Return the reference count of the object. The count returned is generally one higher than you might expect, because it includes the (temporary) reference as an argument to getrefcount().

In an attempt to grok it myself, here's the progression/confusion:

Firstly, should `sys.getrefcount(object)` work on values/literals? (please correct my terminology if I'm wrong), and ***why are the refcounts so random?***

```py
>>> import sys
>>> [sys.getrefcount(i) for i in range (10)]
[320, 195, 128, 43, 69, 24, 32, 18, 44, 17]
>>> [sys.getrefcount(str(i)) for i in range (10)] #refcount of every value is same now (?)
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Then, I tried to explore further

```py
>>> # Let's probe further
>>> import random
>>> [sys.getrefcount(str(random.randint(1,20))) for i in range (10)]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
>>> [sys.getrefcount(str(random.randint(1,20)*'a')) for i in range (10)]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 14, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1] # not every item is same
>>> [sys.getrefcount(random.choice('abcde')) for i in range (10)]
[20, 20, 12, 12, 9, 13, 12, 13, 12, 12]
>>> [sys.getrefcount(str(random.choice('abcde'))) for i in range (10)]
[9, 20, 12, 12, 12, 9, 12, 12, 12, 12]
```

What is going on above? I'm not sure if all the behaviors can be explained with just one misunderstanding that I might have or there are multiple things at play here. Please feel safe in assuming that the above lines were run sequentially in the Python Interpreter and nothing else was there that is not here.

For the question to make more sense, everything began here:

```py
>>> sys.getrefcount(1)
187
>>> a = 1
>>> sys.getrefcount(a)
185
```

EDIT: I get it all, but why should `sys.getrefcount(1)` be so high?

Comment: That's just how many references those objects happen to have. Other stuff in the interpreter is using those objects.

Comment: Why do you think you should get meaningfull numbers for this? _Somewhere_, _someone_ uses a string of `b'` so the refcount wont be 1 or 2 - you cannot control or check how often this is used in python, so why bother?

Answer (score 2):

> Firstly, should sys.getrefcount(object) work on values/literals? (please correct my terminology if I'm wrong)

Yes. The literal is an expression that returns an object. That object might be cached (e.g., small numbers) or not (arbitrary strings).

> , and why are the refcounts so random?

Coincidence/idiosyncracies of the interpreter.

```
>>> [sys.getrefcount(i) for i in range (10)]
[320, 195, 128, 43, 69, 24, 32, 18, 44, 17]
```

Small numbers literals are cached in CPython; they're all referring to the same object in memory, and whatever object is in memory has a reference to them. In this case, CPython might keep a reference to the small numbers cache for loops.

```
>>> [sys.getrefcount(str(i)) for i in range (10)] #refcount of every value is same now (?)
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

These are new objects, not searched in cache.

For the rest, strings are usually cached, and some references were in memory at the time.

```
>>> sys.getrefcount(1)
187
>>> a = 1
>>> sys.getrefcount(a)
185
```

`a` is merely a reference to the (usually cached) "1", and whatever difference there is between refcounts probably refers to whatever process the REPL carries in order to have a reference to the literal and print it.